# Magento showing wrong total records in sales./order grid

Tags: php, mysql, magento, grid, magento-1.9.1

I will try my best to explain what I am doing.

1. I have manually added four columns in grid.php file for sales/order grid.
2. Now it's showing the wrong count in the total records.
3. There are more than 1500 records, but it shows only 1190.
4. So here is the code grid.php file.

   ```
   <?php

   class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
   {
       public function callback_skus($value, $row, $column, $isExport)
       {
           $increment_id = $value;
           $_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($increment_id);
           $_items = $_order->getAllItems();
           $skus="";
           foreach ($_items as $item)
           {
               $skus .= $item->getSku()."<br />";
           }
           return $skus;
       }

       public function __construct()
       {
           parent::__construct();
           $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
           $this->setUseAjax(true);
           $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
           $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
           $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
       }

       /**
       * Retrieve collection class
       *
       * @return string
       */
       protected function _getCollectionClass()
       {
           return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
       }

       protected function _prepareCollection()
       {
           $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

           $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_payment', 'sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id = main_table.entity_id',array('method'));
           $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
           $collection->getSelect()->group('sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id');

           $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_shipment_track', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_shipment_track.order_id',array('track_number'=> new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(DISTINCT `sales_flat_shipment_track`.track_number SEPARATOR ", ")'),'title' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT group_concat(`sales_flat_shipment_track`.title SEPARATOR ", ")FROM `sales_flat_shipment_track` As `sales_flat_shipment_track` WHERE `main_table`.`entity_id` = `sales_flat_shipment_track`.`order_id` )')));
           $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', "main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id AND sales_flat_order_address.address_type='shipping'",array('country_id')); 
           $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_item', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id',array('sku'));
           $collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
           $this->setCollection($collection);


           $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
           foreach($orders as $order){
               $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
               foreach($items as $item){
                   $sku = $item->getSku();
               }
           }
           $collection->getSize();
           $collection->count();
           return parent::_prepareCollection();    
       }

       public function count()
       {
           $this->load();
           return count($this->_prepareColumns);
       }


       protected function _prepareColumns()
       {



           $this->addColumn('sku', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU#'),
               'index' => 'increment_id',
               'width' => '80px',
               'frame_callback' => array($this, 'callback_skus'),
               'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_item.sku',
               ));


           $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
               'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
               'width' => '80px',
               'type'  => 'text',
               'index' => 'increment_id',
               ));

           $this->addColumn('country_id', array(
               'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Country'),
               'width' => '80px',
               'type'  => 'text',
               'index' => 'country_id',
               ));


           $this->addColumn('method', array(
               'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
               'width' => '80px',
               'type'  => 'text',
               'index' => 'method',
               ));


           if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
               $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                   'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                   'index'     => 'store_id',
                   'type'      => 'store',
                   'store_view'=> true,
                   'display_deleted' => true,
                   ));
           }

           $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
               'index' => 'created_at',
               'type' => 'datetime',
               'width' => '100px',
               ));

           $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
               'index' => 'billing_name',
               ));

           $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
               'index' => 'shipping_name',
               ));

           $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
               'index' => 'base_grand_total',
               'type'  => 'currency',
               'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
               ));

           $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
               'index' => 'grand_total',
               'type'  => 'currency',
               'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
               ));

           $this->addColumn('status', array(
               'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
               'index' => 'status',
               'type'  => 'options',
               'width' => '70px',
               'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
               ));

           $this->addColumn('track_number', array(
               'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__(' Track Number'),
               'width' => '80px',
               'type'  => 'text',
               'index' => 'track_number',

               ));


           $this->addColumn('title', array(
               'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Title'),
               'width' => '80px',
               'index' => 'title',

               ));


           if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
               $this->addColumn('action',
                   array(
                       'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                       'width'     => '50px',
                       'type'      => 'action',
                       'getter'     => 'getId',
                       'actions'   => array(
                           array(
                               'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                               'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                               'field'   => 'order_id',
                               'data-column' => 'action',
                               )
                           ),
                       'filter'    => false,
                       'sortable'  => false,
                       'index'     => 'stores',
                       'is_system' => true,
                       ));
           }
           $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

           $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
           $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

           return parent::_prepareColumns();
       }



       protected function _prepareMassaction()
       {
           $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
           $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
           $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

           if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
               $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                   'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                   'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
                   ));
           }

           if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
               $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                   'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                   'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
                   ));
           }

           if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
               $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                   'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                   'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
                   ));
           }

           $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
               'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
               'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
               ));

           $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
               'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
               'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
               ));

           $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
               'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
               'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
               ));

           $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
               'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
               'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
               ));

           $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
               'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
               'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
               ));

           return $this;
       }

       public function getRowUrl($row)
       {
           if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
               return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
           }
           return false;
       }

       public function getGridUrl()
       {
           return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
       }

   }
   ```
5. Now I have written my code for joining table and access it from the grid in _prepareCollections() function.
6. Added 4 columns in _addcolumns() function. I am adding payment method, Sku, title, track_number.

**Problem**

total records 1190 found.

But it should show all 1500 records. 
Please let me know what I have to do.

Also please refer the link for my previous problem [my previous problem link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801686/how-to-add-custom-column-in-sales-order-grid-in-magento/25809902#25809902)

Comment: Could you show how many records in table `sales_flat_order_grid` and table `sales_flat_shipment_track` and how many distinct records in `sales_flat_order_grid` by field `sales_flat_order_grid`

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that.? How would I do that?

Comment: Is my query for retrieving data from database is good?

Comment: And m I joining the tables correctly? ???

Comment: Execute and show results of next queries: `select count(*) from sales_flat_order_grid;` and `select count(distinct entity_id) from sales_flat_order_grid;` and `select count(*) from sales_flat_shipment_track;`

Comment: select count(*) from sales_flat_order_grid;-->1505, select count(distinct entity_id) from sales_flat_order_grid;->1505, select count(*) from sales_flat_shipment_track;->1191.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution(Ryan helped me out). There will not be always all the shipment tracking number and also the payment.

So here we need to use `joinLeft on sales_flat_shipment_track and sales_flat_order_payment.`

Hence it works. ! :)